# Is this kind of ring possible?

Tags: ring-theory

I came up with this question while reading about rings.

> If I have a ring $(R,+,·)$ and $(R,·)$ is a group, what kind of ring would $(R,+,·)$ be, if it's even possible and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be the trivial ring, as $0$ has an inverse, and when $0$ (I mean the neutral element of addition) get's an inverse you always get the trivial ring.

Comment: But how can (R,·) be a group if it's neutral element is not in R. Or would this mean that + and · has same neutral element?

Comment: @Kaltsoon it must be the trivial group, when $(R,\cdot )$ is a group and $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a ring you know that $R=\{ 0\}$ and $(R,\cdot )$ is a trivial group, and the neutral element is for sure in the trivial group (the neutral element of multiplication is $0$ in the trivial ring that only contains a zero

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thanks a lot!